References for Generation of Synthetic Data
What are some of the introductory textbooks/references specifically on the task of generating synthetic data (from real data)? If possible, such a text is expected to cover a range of methods, be it theoretical or applied. Texts with more emphasis on Bayesian methods are perferred.
You can assume the readers have strong background in probability theory (understands topics like stochatsic differential equations) and statistics (understands the statistical decision theory and knows the proofs to basic results), along with familiarity with languages like R/Python and basic machine learning techniques. In fact, the more mathematical the text is, the better.
